# Java More Resourceful Collision Detection

Tags: java, resources, collision-detection, paint

I am making a game in java which involves characters moving around a map and having some solid collision objects (i.e. buildings) placed around the map by reading certain data from a text file. There will be multiple maps where these objects' locations will change. **My question** is would painting a rectangle in a certain color that indicates collision behind such structures **or** would reading mouse coordinates and searching an array of these structures to see if that point lies on a building, thus denying the move or altering, be more resourceful and/or quicker. If painting a rectangle is the best, would leaving it behind the structure or deleting it after detecting for collision be better. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I feel this question is overly broad; could you illustrate with some code?

Comment: Well what code would you need?

Comment: Something that shows the two alternatives without being overly broad. Have you implemented either alternative so far?

Comment: I have done painting a rectangle behind an image, but before I coded the characters moving I wanted to check this. Basically a class, `Collision` creates a rectangle with a color of 0,0,1. This is the same size and in the same location as the image. Order in paint allows me to get a screen with the map background and just collision rectangles (so seeing if move coordinate is 0,0,1 in color) and check for collision, then paint character, then structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my junior year in college I worked on a Collision detection system algorithm for the windows phone. It is hardly perfect but it was EXTREMELY efficient and can be adapted to a majority of games.

The way that it worked was pretty simple. There were two types of objects; Collidable objects (such as enemies or buildings) and Objects that you wish to check for collisions with these collidable objects.

I had this idea when I was going through a data structures class and we spoke about Linked Lists. I thought what if each link was a collidable object that you could stick your game objects that were already created in it. Then as the game objects moved around you would have a lightweight way of checking their locations for collisions. Thus my system was born.

All it really is, is a class that fires off either every game cycle or when ever you choose to check for collisions. You give it your players location, or bullet location or what ever object you want to see if it is colliding with something and it searches all of the collidable object locations and conducts test to see if they are overlapping.

The real efficiency of it comes into play when you add in a second element (Locations AND quadrant)

For Example if I break the phone screen up into for parts and I know which quadrant my player or bullet is in I can choose to only scan a list of collidable objects that are within that quadrant. Thus cutting your search algorithm to a fourth of its origonal size. 
[image]

There are many different ways of detecting collisions. This was a simple example I used in my class to show how you could detect two circles colliding that were actually squares. As you can see simply by taking the center point coords of the circles and the radius's you can calculate the hypotenuse and determine where or if they are touching. 
[image]

Good luck! if you have any questions feel free to ask!

Comment: I think your collision detection may be a tad advanced for me but the quadrant idea was very useful. I already have it so it only paints the amount of map that would fit on a monitor screen so by using those variables I could just display the collisions in that area. Thank you very much for making me realize this. Maybe at that point it wouldn't really matter?

Comment: I am mainly just concerned with your use of the word "painting" are you actually drawing rectangles to the screen then placing objects over them? If so it might work in the short term but when you start adding more and more work load its going to bog down quick. It is much faster to just sit down with a white board or a piece of paper and figure out an algorithm to theoretically draw a square. For example I don't ACTUALLY draw a triangle I just do the math.

Comment: I am actually painting a rectangle to the screen which is now making me concerned due to the same reason as you stated but more for when many units are in one patch of screen. I suppose theoretically would be best.

Comment: It takes a little work to wrap your mind around things you can't see on the screen but once you start thinking this way you will save yourself a TON of head aches and efficiency issues. Just keep it simple. Make an object that has X,Y int values in it and a reference to what ever it represents like your enemy or a wall. Then take that object and stick it in a list. Boom you have a list you can search for collisions.

Comment: Good point and I'll probably have to do that, but I just had an idea that isn't working right now when I tried to implement it but could I write a `MouseListener` in my `Structure class` that could detect a click on a `Structure` object and react in a way that it should? This would then be my collision detection. I extend the structures as `JLabel`s.

Comment: Using an event is one way to make things happen but I would hardly call it a collision unless the parameters of the game specifically said every time someone clicks on an object there is a collision.

Comment: What if I want to know if a ball collides with a rectangular paddle?

Answer (score 0):

The last reply in this [posting](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1349483) may help you out. It is a simple maze. The structure of the maze is controlled by a data file which simply contains 0, 1 to indicate a path or a wall. You navigate through the maze using the arrow keys. When an arrow key is pressed the code checks to make sure the next square is not a wall.