# Is the ball touching one of the paddles?

Tags: java, collision-detection

I'm making apong game, in a boolean method in the Paddle class I want to determine if the ball touching any of the two paddles, I'm struggling of finding the proper logic...

here are the variables:

```
// instance variables 
private Screen theScreen;
private MyroRectangle theRectangle;
private int topLeftX;
private int topLeftY;


// constants
private final int HEIGHT = 100;         //the paddle's fixed height
private final int WIDTH = 5;            //the paddle's fixed width
private final int PIXELS_PER_MOVE = 20; //the number of pixels a paddle can move either up or down in one timestep
```

here is the method: * this method is just to determine if the ball touch or not it doesn't do anything with bounce the ball back

```
public boolean isTouching(Ball b)
{   

    boolean t = false;
    if ((theScreen.getWidth()-(b.getX() + b.getRadius())) >= theScreen.getWidth()-theRectangle.getCenterX() )
          {
t= true;
}

    return t;
```

also I tried:

```
 if ((b.getX() > theRectangle.getCenterX()/2) && (b.getY() < theRectangle.getCenterY()/2))
```

==========
** the methods of the ball class that might be needed:

```
getX()
getY()
getRadius()
```

==============

** the Rectangle class:

```
getCenterX()
getCenterY()
```

===============

** the Screen class:

```
getWidth()
getHeight()
```

I just want to determine at least on of the conditions then I can figure out the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

In my junior year in college I worked on a Collision detection system algorithm for the windows phone. It is hardly perfect but it was EXTREMELY efficient and can be adapted to a majority of games.

The way that it worked was pretty simple. There were two types of objects; Collidable objects (such as enemies or buildings) and Objects that you wish to check for collisions with these collidable objects.

I had this idea when I was going through a data structures class and we spoke about Linked Lists. I thought what if each link was a collidable object that you could stick your game objects that were already created in it. Then as the game objects moved around you would have a lightweight way of checking their locations for collisions. Thus my system was born.

Basically what it comes down to is using

> C (or the distance between to points) = SqrRoot(A^2 + B^2) - radius of ball

this formula should look very familiar to you.

You can see the full answer on this question:
[Java More Resourceful Collision Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764354/java-more-resourceful-collision-detection/14764628#14764628)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be seen as solving the question if two 2d-areas, the paddle (a rectangle) and the ball (a circle) intersect. You can just google/wiki formulas for that.

If you don't want to go into the math for solving the problem through geometry, package java.awt.geom contains classes that can do the calculations for you, namely java.awt.Area. You would just create Area instances for paddle and ball and then call the intersects() method to know if they collided.